# LinkedList with if statements?

Tags: java, list, if-statement

So i got this one task to do, about LinkedList, you can take a look on my Main file, also got to mention that my "//The conditions" part is wrong and I just put something as an idea, but that's actually not really working

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args){
    
        ArrayList nokiaAL = new ArrayList();
        LinkedList phoneAL = new LinkedList();
        
        //input
        Smartphone a = new Smartphone("Nokia","Nokia 7 Plus",1300,260101);
        Smartphone b = new Smartphone("Samsung","Galaxy S8",900,220100);
        Smartphone c = new Smartphone("Xiaomi","Mi 10",1500,150031);
        Smartphone d = new Smartphone("Nokia","3310",250,101001);
        Smartphone e = new Smartphone("Samsung","Galaxy Y",400,774101);
        Smartphone f = new Smartphone("Apple","iPhone 7",1100,316300);
        
        phoneAL.insertAtFront(f);
        phoneAL.insertAtFront(e);
        phoneAL.insertAtFront(d);
        phoneAL.insertAtFront(c);
        phoneAL.insertAtFront(b);
        phoneAL.insertAtFront(a);
        
        //process
        Object r = (Object) phoneAL.getFirst();
        while (r != null) {
            System.out.print(" "+r);
            r = (Object) phoneAL.getNext();
        }
        
        //The conditions
        //If nokia + the price $1200+, it will save all the info about nokia
        //If brand samsung + model Galaxy Y, It will count the total of the phone
        Object obj;
        int countSamsung = 0;
        for(int i=0;i<phoneAL.size();i++){
            obj = phoneAL.get(i);
            Smartphone obj2 = (Smartphone) obj;
            if(obj2.getBrand().equalsIgnoreCase("Nokia")){
                nokiaAL.add(obj2);
            }
            if(obj2.getBrand().equalsIgnoreCase("Samsung")){
                if(obj2.getModel().equalsIgnoreCase("Galaxy Y")){
                    countSamsung++;
                }
            }
        }
        
        //output
        System.out.println("\n");
        System.out.println("Details about Nokia phone more than RM1200:"+nokiaAL.toString());
        System.out.println("Quantity of Samsung model Galaxy Y: " + countSamsung);
    }
}
```

I know how to print all the details in the LinkedList, the main point here is, you can't add or change anything of other .java files, you can only edit the Main.java file, is it even possible? here's my Smartphone and LinkedList code.

```
public class Smartphone {
    
    String brand;//e.g: Nokia, Samsung
    String model;//e.g: Lumia, Galaxy Y, Note S
    double price;
    int warranty;//warranty (in year)

    Smartphone() {
        
    }
    
public Smartphone(String a, String b, double c, int d){
    this.brand=a;
    this.model=b;
    this.price=c;
    this.warranty=d;
}    

public String getBrand(){
    return brand;
}

public String getModel(){
    return model;
}

public double getPrice(){
    return price;
}

public int getWarranty(){
    return warranty;
}

public String toString(){
    return "\n\nBrand: "+brand +"\nModel: "+ model +"\nPrice: $"+ price +"\nWarranty: "+ warranty;
    }
}
```

```
public class LinkedList 
{
   private Node first;
   private Node last;
   private Node current; 
   
    public LinkedList()
    {
        first = null;
                last = null;
                current = null;  
    }
    
    public boolean isEmpty(){   
            return (first == null); }   
    
    public void insertAtFront(Object insertItem){
            Node newNode = new Node(insertItem);
       
      
            if (isEmpty()){
        first = newNode;
        last = newNode;
      }else{
          newNode.next = first;
          first = newNode;
      }
    }
        public void insertAtBack(Object insertItem){
            Node newNode = new Node(insertItem);
        
        if(isEmpty()){
            first = newNode;
            last = newNode;
        }else{
            last.next = newNode;
            last = newNode;
        }
    }
        public Object removeFromFront(){
            Object removeItem = null;
        
        if(isEmpty()){
            return removeItem;
        }
        
        removeItem = first.data;
        
          if(first == last){
            first = null;
            last = null;
            }else
            first = first.next;
           
    return removeItem;
    }
    
    public Object removeFromBack(){
    Object removeItem = null;
        
      if(isEmpty())
      {
        return removeItem;
      }
        
      removeItem = last.data;
          
        if (first == last)
      {
         first = null;
         last = null;
      }else{
         current = first;
         while(current.next != last)
            current = current.next;
         last = current;
         last.next = null;
        }
        
      return removeItem;
     }
     
     public Object getFirst(){
        if(isEmpty())
          return null;
        else
        {
            current = first;
            return current.data;
        }
    }
     
     public Object getNext(){
        if(current == last)
          return null;
        else
        {
            current = current.next;
            return current.data;
        }
    }    
}
```

As I said before, I can print all the details of the phones, but how to really use it as conditions, like If-else statement? for example, if(obj.getBrand().equalsIgnoreCase("Nokia")){} , I can achieve this with ArrayList but since this is LinkedList task, So I'm still figuring this out without even know if its possible or not. I hope someone would understand this and able to help. TQ

here's my node code for the LinkedList

```
public class Node {
    Object data;
    Node next;
    
    Node(Object obj){
        data=obj;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm in trouble to understand your needs... What is really your issue? Because in your example you are able to get the object, so you can iterate and use if clauses

Comment: Also, you are iterating use get(i) but as you are using linked list (and in your example you dont have this method implemented), you should iterate with getNext (also will have a better performance).

Comment: I'm stuck at the if statement and not really know how to use it with while loop for this LinkedList, especially with this specific LinkedList.java that was given in order to do the task, because I can't change it to add maybe idk, "size()" , "display()" or anything..yeah that if else method is wrong btw, I just put it there just to show my task

Comment: Do you really have to implement LinkedList by yourself? Why don't you use the original LinkedList?

Comment: idk man..this assignment really screwed up my head :<

Comment: First things first: **you should *never* use raw types**. Always provide the necessary type arguments. In your case, you have an `ArrayList`, which is expecting a type argument. You should provide it, i.e. `ArrayList<Smartphone>`.

Comment: And note: importing java.util.* whilst also defining your OWN classes that have the same name as some standard classes from that package: be really careful about that. Dont reuse standard class names, and especially when you import them, too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should iterate using while and validating if the list has ended.
Diferently from an ArrayList, that you can directly acess the vector positions, in a linked list you should walk from node to node. Also, in your example you only implement a `getNext()` method and not a `get(i)`.

Example:

```
Object aux = linkedList.getFirst();
while(aux != null) {
  // your business logic here
  aux = linkedList.getNext();
}
```

As you dont make the use of generics in your implementation, to acess your object data, you will need to use cast or make use of generics in your implementation.

Cast way:

```
while(aux != null) {
  phoneObject = (Smartphone) aux;
  // your business logic here
  if(phoneObject.getBrand().equalsIgnoreCase("Nokia")){
    System.out.println("Phone brand == Nokia");
  }
  aux = linkedList.getNext();
}
```

In the generic approach, you will also need to change the LinkedList implementation and Node implementation.

LinkedList:

```
public class LinkedList<T>
{
   private Node<T> first;
   private Node<T> last;
   private Node<T> current; 

   public T getFirst(){
        if(isEmpty())
          return null;
        else
        {
            current = first;
            return current.data;
        }
    }

    public T getNext(){
        if(current == last)
          return null;
        else
        {
            current = current.next;
            return current.data;
        }
    }

    // add other methods here
}
```

Node:

```
public class Node<T> {
    T data;
    Node<T> next;

    // add other methods here
}
```

Main:

```
LinkedList<Smartphone> linkedList = new LinkedList<Smartphone>();

// add objects

Smartphone aux = linkedList.getFirst();
while(aux != null) {
  // no need to cast, because of generics use
  if(aux.getBrand().equalsIgnoreCase("Nokia")){
    System.out.println("Phone brand == Nokia");
  }
  // your business logic here
  aux = linkedList.getNext();
}
```

Your `getNext()` method, returns `null` if your list has ended, so our stop criteria is `aux == null`. Our loop will execute while aux is not null, execute all your business logic (if clauses or what ever validation you want to do) and in the end of the loop, you will set the next object to `aux` variable.

Comment: The class Object does not have the method `getBrand()`.

Comment: thanks for that, but how can I really use linked list as condition in if else statement? for example like you did, if(aux.getBrand().....) but the aux refers to linkedlist and I don't have the info of the phones in linked list, but it all stored in Smartphone.java and how to call all of the info throught it? at this point, idk what im sayin tbh xD

Comment: That's right, it needs a cast or generic. I will update the answer

Comment: @ZachUnlimited i've added 2 ways you can use and iterate. If you are not able to change the linked list implementation, you could use cast. If you can change the LinkedList implementation (but in your description you said you can only change Main file), you can use the other approach (generics). In the two examples you are acessing th smartphone object, so now you can acess and manipulate the data

Comment: Wow! thanks alot Glim! Cast way method it is! that's really helpful..thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should add a generic parameter to your LinkedList.

```
class LinkedList<T> {
    private Node<T> first;
    private Node<T> last;
    private Node<T> current;
    ....
}

class Node<T> {
    T data;
    Node<T> next;

    Node(T obj) {
        data = obj;
    }
}
```

Then you can only add objects of that type to your list.

```
LinkedList<Smartphone> phoneList = new LinkedList<>();
```

But of course, if you can you really should not implement LinkedList by yourself but use the existing one! That's far more easier and safer to use.

```
List<Smartphone> nokiaList = new ArrayList<>();
List<Smartphone> phoneList = new LinkedList<>();

//input
phoneList.add(new Smartphone("Nokia", "Nokia 7 Plus", 1300, 260101));
phoneList.add(new Smartphone("Samsung", "Galaxy S8", 900, 220100));
phoneList.add(new Smartphone("Xiaomi", "Mi 10", 1500, 150031));
phoneList.add(new Smartphone("Nokia", "3310", 250, 101001));
phoneList.add(new Smartphone("Samsung", "Galaxy Y", 400, 774101));
phoneList.add(new Smartphone("Apple", "iPhone 7", 1100, 316300));

//The conditions
//If nokia + the price $1200+, it will save all the info about nokia
//If brand samsung + model Galaxy Y, It will count the total of the phone
Object obj;
int countSamsung = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < phoneList.size(); i++) {
    Smartphone phone = phoneList.get(i);
    if (phone.getBrand().equalsIgnoreCase("Nokia")) {
        nokiaList.add(phone);
    }
    if (phone.getBrand().equalsIgnoreCase("Samsung")) {
        if (phone.getModel().equalsIgnoreCase("Galaxy Y")) {
            countSamsung++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "you can't add or change anything of other .java files, you can only edit the Main.java file"